# cannot determine the right context to generate stub into

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two files (Classes), one CustomerDal which contain functions to get data from database and CustomerBal which contains functions that manipulate on data returned by CustomerDal.

I want to create a new function in CustomerDal class so I write the syntax like following in CustomerBal an use **"ctrl + ."** to [generate method stub](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/01/01/generate-method-stubs-using-shortcut-key-in-visual-studio/) in CustomerDal

```
customerBalObj.GetCustomerDetail(string customerId);
```

But I am getting following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error message states but I closed, reopened the file again but did't work. Finally I closed the solution and reopened it and it works fine.